# Properly play H.264 media on VLC Player

Tags: media-player

I installed VLC Player on my Galaxy S7 to try playback from an external hard disk shared via BeagleBone Black. The storage contains both x264 and h264 media. VLC plays x264 smoothly but very slowly on H.264, it keeps buffering the video and the images gets distorted. I thought the bottleneck is in the BBB so I tried running the same file from PC works perfectly. Is H.264 playback well supported on android? VLC Player is the only app with proper local network share discovery, other apps like MX Player, KMPlayer, etc. either does not support local network or setting it up is a mess.

Comment: Try changing the settings. Start with hardware decoding, if no changes, try changing "Deblocking filter settings" and/or "Enable frame skip".

Comment: None of that works. But what I found is that I played a 2.5H movie (5GB in size and H.264 encoded) that I have and it played well and it barely gives any buffering or distorted image. At first I was testing a series all episodes in H.264 so I test other episodes and it gives me same behavior. Seems like I will have to test the rest of the media on the storage because I am starting to suspect that the media itself is corrupted. Although it plays well on my PC from the storage.

Comment: Also I noticed - encoding wise - the difference between the movie and any episode is that the movie's audio is encoded in AC3 while the episodes in E-AC, so I converted the episode's audio to AC3 but it still not playing smoothly.

Comment: Tried different content, still the problem with H.264 content not a specific file.

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidFAQ/ Check the question & answer on HD videos. Or try the forum: https://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=35&sid=c31492f68a22bbaeb1c663a74b1dfe00

Comment: It appears to be a hardware issue, when I play anything a bit far away from the board it becomes slow and distorted. I believe a better hardware would do the trick